# Google Analytics request in .NET Web Application. Do I need to use OAUTH or can i use API key only for request?

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-analytics

I cannot find the information on this question in an accurate manner, and is becoming a bit problematic to me. Hopefully someone can help guide me to the right direction. Do I have to use OAuth authentication to hit the analytic's API for all of our accounts, or can I just use a shared key? every example, and only finding examples for java script, but none for .NET, show it using a autho type authentication for authenticating the user. We are not allowing any public users to hit our accounts though, only our development team. So what do I need to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each member of your dev team is gong to have to accept the Oauth in order to login.  Oauth is based on the User that logs in.    Not the google analytics account itself.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping we could use the analytic API with a shared key type get request, and not have to use the Oauth method.  Thanks again.